# Top Menu - Align One Item to right

Tags: html, css, alignment, text-align

I want to align the "Login" item to the right.
I am pretty new to HTML and CSS. I don't even know if this is the right approach to creating a horizontal menu bar.
Something like this: [How I want it to be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1oO8.jpg)

Here is my code:

HTML:

```css
@import url("FONTS/stylesheet.css");
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<body>

<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a class="loginnav" href="#login">Login</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to change?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add this code into your CSS and it works `.topnav .loginnav {float:right;}`

```css
@import url("FONTS/stylesheet.css");
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}


.topnav a:hover {
    background: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
.topnav .loginnav {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<body>

<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a class="loginnav" href="#login">Login</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
@import url("FONTS/stylesheet.css");
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}

.right {
position: absolute;

top: 8px;
right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">
<body>

<div class="topnav">
  <div class="left">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
  <a class="loginnav" href="#login">Login</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is probably a bad way, but it works!

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to help you fast :P

Answer (score 0):

Change `.topnav` to `display: flex`, and add `margin-left: auto;` to `.loginnav`:

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.topnav a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.topnav a:hover {
  background: #ddd;
  color: black;
}

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

.loginnav {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a class="loginnav" href="#login">Login</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your code .

```
    .loginnav{
        margin-left:800px;
    }
```

Comment: when width of viewport will change this will not work

Comment: then  you just can use

         `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Or
 
       `@media`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it with flex and auto margin the login from the left:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.topnav {
    background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
}

.topnav a {
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}

.loginnav {
    margin-left: auto
}

.topnav a:hover {
    background: #ddd;
    color: black;
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style1.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

<body>

<div class="topnav">
  <a class="active" href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a class="loginnav" href="#login">Login</a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Note that I removed the `inline-block` from the `a` tag and added to the `.topnav` the rule `display: flex;`

First, to display it as flex, and then to align these items to the end.